# Get All Directories of a Folder Path Recursively into my Poco

Tags: c#, recursion, directory

I wrote a poco like this :

```
public class MyDirectory
{
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public List<MyDirectory> MyDirectories { get; set; }
}
```

then I wrote 2 methods like this

```
    private static List<MyDirectory> lst = new List<MyDirectory>();
    private static void DirSearch(string dir)
    {
            var dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(dir);

            foreach (string d in dirs)
            {
                var ddd = new MyDirectory();
                ddd.Path = d;
                ddd.MyDirectories = GetList(Directory.GetDirectories(d));
                lst.Add(ddd);
                DirSearch(d);
            }            
    }

    private static List<MyDirectory> GetList(string[] list)
    {
        var lst = new List<MyDirectory>();
        foreach (var l in list)
        {
            lst.Add(new MyDirectory() { Path = l });
        }
        return lst;
    }
```

but I does not work Can anybody change it to working method ?
I dont know How fill my Poco correctly. I need recursively method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to recursively load directories then you  don't GetList method. The method DirSearch is sufficient but need some refactoring like below:

```
private static List<MyDirectory> DirSearch(string directory)
{
    var directories = new List<MyDirectory>();
    foreach (var l in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(directory))
    {
        directories.Add(new MyDirectory
        {
            Path = l,
            MyDirectories = DirSearch(l)
        });
    }
    return directories;
}
```

Notice in the snippet I'm using `Directory.EnumerateDirectories` instead of `Directory.GetDirectories`. I do this because the latter isn't performant.

To call this method just do this:

```
lst = DirSearch(pathToYourDirectory);
```

You can make it better by using `IEnumerable` instead of `List` as type of `MyDirectories` property.

Your code will finally look like this :

```
public class MyDirectory
{
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<MyDirectory> MyDirectories { get; set; }
}

private static IEnumerable<MyDirectory> DirSearch(string directory)
{
    return Directory.EnumerateDirectories(directory).Select(l => new MyDirectory
    {
        Path = l,
        MyDirectories = DirSearch(l)
    });
}
```

Indeed your static property `lst` need to be of type `IEnumerable<MyDirectory>` also.

By doing those changes you will be able to start using each instance of `MyDirectory` instead of waiting all subdirectories to be returned when using `List`.

Comment: Can you explain more about what is difference between EnumerateDirectories and GetDirectories ?

Comment: Just replace Files with Directories

Answer (score 0):

Instead of do recursive, you can use this code

```
Directory.GetDirectories(path, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
```

Comment: No I dont need this solution My problem is not get folder, My problem is fill classes recursively

Comment: whats your goal dude ? you want to get all folders in a poco, Am i right ?

Comment: I want fill MyDirectory poco correctly this class have self relation so I  want each path have related path as list inti the MyDirectories propertis

Answer (score 0):

Create cunstructor for your POCO.

```
public class MyDirectory
    {
        public MyDirectory()
        {
            MyDirectories = new List<MyDirectory>();
        }
        public string Path { get; set; }
        public List<MyDirectory> MyDirectories { get; set; }
    }
```

Recursive Method:

```
private MyDirectory FindRecursiveDirectories(string dir)
    {
        var rootDirectory = new MyDirectory();
        rootDirectory.Path = dir;

        foreach (var subDirectory in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(dir))
        {
            var myDir = FindRecursiveDirectories(subDirectory);
            rootDirectory.MyDirectories.Add(myDir);
        }

        return rootDirectory;
    }
```

Finally call `FindRecursiveDirectories` Method.

```
var result = FindRecursiveDirectories(yourDirectory);
```